# nt authority/system user has no right to send Outlook Office365 emails with attachment

Tags: user-accounts, office365, scheduled-tasks, microsoft-outlook-2016

- System: Windows 10
- email: Office 2016 with Outlook 365 account
- Outlook programatic access: set to never warn
- attachment file type: self configured file type with number e.g. *.010 - marked by some systems as notepad file, by some systems as pdf file - depending on local users.

I have two scheduled tasks:

1. one that needs to check daily the Outlook Inbox for a certain email and attachment and download the attachment to a certain file.
2. one that needs to create daily an email with an attachment file (see above description) and place it into the Outlook Outbox without sending.

I would like to configure both task with nt authority/system (SID S-1-5-18). I can configure and save the task with nt authority/system, but it does not perform the job, the task keeps running and never ends.
Outlook programatic access: set to never warn.

Using the regular user it works - but this gives other problems and this described problem is the source.

The program running in the background, called by the scheduled task can perform the duty in case set to nt authority/system, without using outlook but using only the Office 365 server access.

Therefore the problem seems to be with Outlook and user rights.
Outlook.exe itself, the data file and the data folders have the system user mentioned under security with full access and all accesses.

Is there anything I could do in the regedit?

Comment: You may try contacting nt authority/system support for more information.

Comment: When I ask Microsoft the reply would not be in this forum. Therefore I would prefer a reply here.